# ^(.*)$ vs ^([a-zA-Z0-9])$ in htaccess files

Tags: string, .htaccess

what is the different between both of them? `^(.*)$` vs `^([a-zA-Z0-9])$` i guess the implementation of them are depends at how the programmer itself, but is there any security reasons for this? i just want to know the different.

Thanks for any correction :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(.*)$` will match any number of any characters after the beginning of the string and before the end of the string whereas `^([a-zA-Z0-9])$` will match a single lower case or upper case latin alphabet letter or number immediately after the beginning of the string and immediately preceding the end of the string. If you want to understand it better, I highly recommend this [intro to regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)